# Stack Exchange Android App: Email already in use

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I have somehow lost the ability to login to Stack Exchange via the Android app. This is on a [Samsung Galaxy Note 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_4). I desire to login via my Google account, as that is what I do when using Stack Exchange sites using desktop browsers.

See below the stack of screenshots showing the various screens on the cellphone, and onto which I have drawn what buttons I clicked.

I am at a loss to know how to rectify this situation.

[image: Stack of screenshots]

OT: At the very bottom is the Ubuntu commands I used to create such an image.

```
convert \
-background lightblue -fill blue -font fixed -pointsize 40 \
$(ls tempFileForShare* | awk '{printf("label:%s %s \n", $1, $1)}') \
label:"Above stack of images was created using the following\ncommand-line, in Ubuntu, using ImageMagick convert command" \
'Screenshot from 2016-02-27 22-56-41.png' \
-append out.png
```

EDIT #1:

See below my second attempt at logging in. It results in this error:

```
`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you're trying to *sign up* a new account, not log in. Instead, open the navigation drawer on the left by swiping the left edge of the screen to the right, and choose the top button (I forgot the name, sign up or sign in?). Admitted, it's a bug that the app doesn't provide option to log in from there.

Comment: The [least astonishing thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) would be to make "Email already in use" retry the authentication as a login.

Comment: @AndrewT. See EDIT #1 in the description that I added just now. Swiping had no effect, so instead I presumed clicking on the navigation drawer icon was equivalent. That ended up with a completely different error as the last screenshot showed.

Comment: @DamianYerrick I agree. But see EDIT #1 where I'm seeing a new error from attempting to login using Google.

Comment: I couldn't find existing feature-request for the original issue, but for EDIT #1, see ['key' is not valid for passed 'access_token', token not found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232338/android-app-key-is-not-valid-for-passed-access-token-token-not-found)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for that link!  What worked me is described in the comment at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232338/key-is-not-valid-for-passed-access-token-token-not-found-when-trying-to-l#comment775183_234866  I did not logout/login to Stack Exchange from any desktop machine.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.0.85.

The "Going to sign up instead of Log In or Sign Up" and "Email already in use" issues are fixed here: [Impossible to login when launched from other app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266920/impossible-to-login-when-launched-from-other-app/277829#277829)

The key and access_token issue is fixed here: ["'key' is not valid for passed 'access_token', token not found" when trying to login using Google on Android SE app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232338/key-is-not-valid-for-passed-access-token-token-not-found-when-trying-to-l/276356#276356)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is found at ["'key' is not valid for passed 'access_token', token not found" when trying to login using Google on Android SE app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232338/key-is-not-valid-for-passed-access-token-token-not-found-when-trying-to-l#comment775183_234866)

Just uninstall and reinstall the Stack Exchange App.

Comment: ... just close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's not quite a duplicate. The other question is about login failing without a reinstall. This question is about not treating sign up the same way as login when the account already exists.